# Error: @expo/cli tried to access glob, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound

Tags: expo, yarn-v2

I just created new react-native expo project via yarn 2.  And getting error:

Error yarn start:

```
PS D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators> yarn start
D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.pnp.cjs:21723
      Error.captureStackTrace(firstError);
            ^

Error: @expo/cli tried to access glob, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: glob
Required by: @expo/cli@npm:0.7.3 (via D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\)

Require stack:
- D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js
- D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\doctor\typescript\TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.js
- D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\startAsync.js
- D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\index.js
- D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\bin\cli
    at require$$0.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.pnp.cjs:21723:13)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at require$$0.Module._load (D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.pnp.cjs:21612:31)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at require$$0.Module._extensions..js (D:\Files\Projects\my-rn-journey\other-navigators\.pnp.cjs:21767:33)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

App.js is blank. Just contains hello world text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just noticed expo doesn't support Plugnplay that comes from yarn v2. So we need node_modules.

Just run these:

```
> yarn config set nodeLinker node-modules
> yarn
```

Comment: This is a great find, thank you. It worked for me too. Would you happen to have supporting documentation?

Comment: I think this GitHub issues provides some good further context and link to relevant documentation https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1073